# Rails 3 locale - path to locale tag too long?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, translation, locale, i18n-gem

I've just noticed silly error with locales - when the path for specific locale tag is too long e.g. `t('placeholders.organization.participantsNo')` then there is a `locale translation missing` error, but when I modify locales on my site and in locale file to `t('placeholders.org.partNo')` it works fine - why? Is that means locale tag paths has limited chars to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A translation's key is not limited in the number of characters - a meaningful and nested namespace schema is even encouraged.

Could it be that `placeholders.organization` already has a translation and therefore can't have the sub translation `participantsNo` ?

In any case the origin of your translations missing error is not coming from the number of characters in the key.